# An estimating problem of integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^n)\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n) $.

Let $g(x):=\frac{1}{\vert x\vert^{n-2}}\,,n\gt3$ and $n$ is integer.

Then $g\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb R^n)$ and is bounded outside the ball $B_r(0)$ for any given $r\gt 0$, where the notation "$L^1_{loc}(\mathbb R^n)$" means $g$ is integrable in any compact sets in $\mathbb R^n$.

Let $e_i :=(0,0,...,1,0,...,0)$, where $1$ is at the i-th term.

**My problem is how to show: $$\lim_{r\to 0}\lim_{h\to 0}\int_{B_r(x)}\frac{g(x+he_i-y)-g(x-y)}{h}\,f(y)dy=0$$**

Attempt $1$: I note that for each fixed $h\gt0$, $$\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{B_r(x)}\frac{g(x+he_i-y)-g(x-y)}{h}\,f(y)dy=0.$$ So if we can exchange the limits, then we are done. But I don't know if we can exchange.

Attempt $2$: Also I note that, if we can exchange the limit and integral, i.e. $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}$ and $\int$, then we are also done. But I can't find a dominated function to use the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

I spent one day on thinking this estimate, but I can't figure it out. I am frustrated now...

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f$ is in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$ too, so$$\left|\frac{g(x+he_i-y)-g(x-y)}{h}\,f(y)\right|\leq\|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}\left|\frac{g(x+he_i-y)-g(x-y)}{h}\right|\\\leq 2\|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}\left|\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x-y)\right|$$
uniformly for $h$ small enough,
so $2\|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}\left|\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}\right|$ would be a dominating function (which is clearly integrable) for the case $x\neq 0$. Uniformly, because we can make the ball $B_r(x)$ compact (for $r$ small enough) and take the closure and note that $\left|\frac{g(x+he_i-y)-g(x-y)}{h}\right|$ is decreasing as $h$ approaches $0$, so uniform convergence follows from Dini's theorem and thus the inequality holds uniformly for $h$ small enough.

For the case $x=0$ (actually for all $x$), the monotone convergence theorem can be used, since $\left|\frac{g(x+he_i-y)-g(x-y)}{h}\right|$ is decreasing as $h$ approaches $0$.

Comment: Why should $\left|\frac{g(x+he_i-y)-g(x-y)}{h}\right|\leq 2\left|\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x-y)\right|$ hold uniformly?

Comment: @detnvvp Making the ball $B_r(x)$ compact by taking the closure and noting that $\left|\frac{g(x+he_i-y)-g(x-y)}{h}\right|$ is decreasing in $h$. Then uniform convergence follows from Dini's theorem and thus the inequality holds uniformly for $h$ small enough.

Comment: There is a problem with uniform convergence, though, since the function goes to $\infty$ at $0$. I think that this will work if $x\neq 0$, but for $x=0$ something else is needed.

Comment: Hi Phenotype, why is $\vert \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i} \vert$ integrable? The trick to use polar coordinate seems failing.

Comment: @detnvvp We can excise the point $x=0$, since it has only zero measure. But I don't know why $\left \vert \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i} \right\vert$ is integrable, could you tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: @KitWong $\left \vert \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i} \right\vert=|-n+2|\frac{|x_i|}{|x|^{n-1}}\leq (n-2)\frac{|x|}{|x|^{n-1}}=(n-2)g(x)$ and $g$ is integrable.

Comment: I think it should be $\left \vert \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i} \right\vert=|-n+2|\frac{|x_i|}{|x|^{n}}\leq (n-2)\frac{1}{|x|^{n-1}}$, since $\left \vert \frac{\partial \vert x\vert}{\partial x_i}\right\vert=\left \vert \frac{x_i}{\vert x \vert}\right\vert.$ But it's enough since $\frac{1}{\vert x\vert^{n-1}}$ is integrable if we use the polar coordinate integral. Thanks Phenotype!

Comment: We can exclude the point $x=0$, but we still have to consider the points that are arbitrarily close to it, and close to it the function is unbounded. This causes a problem, since we cannot use uniform convergence.

Comment: @KitWong You're right, I applied the chain rule with mid-variable $|x|^2$ and made an error (luckily you can conclude the same about integrability).

Comment: @detnvvp You're right too, my argument doesn't hold for $x=0$. However, the monotone convergence theorem applies for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, since $\left|\frac{g(x+he_i-y)-g(x-y)}{h}\right|$ is decreasing as $h\downarrow 0$.

Comment: @ThePhenotype Hi Phenotype, how do you obtain the fact that the difference quotient is decreasing in $h$? I cannot see that. Thanks!

Comment: @ThePhenotype I write $p(h):=\left|\frac{g(x+he_i-y)-g(x-y)}{h}\right|$ and I try to prove that $p'(h)\lt 0$ when $h$ is small. But I cannot deal with some terms of it, and I fail to prove its negativity. Could you tell me why $p'\lt 0$ when $h$ is small, thanks!